Данные контрагентов 1С
Получил список всех сущностей в 1С, но среди них не могу найти Каталог Поставщиков и Каталог покупателей, как называются их каталоги?
Данные по каталогам получал через эту ссылку
http://localhost/mc/odata/standard.odata/$metadata

Данные по всем контрагентам можно получить по этой ссылке
http://localhost/mc/odata/standard.odata/Catalog_Контрагенты$format=json
